# Can we convert all XML tags to lowercase in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

While using Beautifulsoup and HTMl parser the tags are converted to lower case. But how can we implement while using LXML parser. In the below case i am not able to print the output.But if i parse using html parser. it works fine. can any one please help me out?

```
html_doc = """
<html><HEAD><title>The Dormouse's story</title></HEAD>

<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<p class="story">...</p>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "xml")

print soup.head
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the XML parser to parse HTML. HTML is case-insensitive, but XML is not.

You can parse HTML with `lxml` just fine, just use the HTML modus:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
>>> soup.head
<head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
```

if you insist on using the XML parser, you'll have to match the case of the input element:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "xml")
>>> soup.head
>>> soup.HEAD
<HEAD><title>The Dormouse's story</title></HEAD>
```

If you instead want to handle XML and do that case insensitive, stick to the ElementTree API provided by `lxml`, and do not use BeautifulSoup at all.  You'd then have to use a [regular expression XPath search](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath):

```
regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
tree.xpath('//*[re:test(., '^head$', 'i')]', namespaces={'re':regexpNS})
```

which would find all elements with the name `head`, case insensitively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just gave a sample example which is HTML. Is there any way to implement if the input is real XML.

Comment: Finally a solution please share, because is very dificult to deal with Soup Services.